# selecting other row element after aggregate in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I would like to select the youngest person in each group and categorize it by gender

so this is my initial data

```
 data1
       ID Age Gender Group 
    1 A01  25   m     a
    2 A02  35   f     b
    3 B03  45   m     b
    4 C99  50   m     b
    5 F05  60   f     a          
    6 X05  65   f     a
```

I would like to have this

```
Gender Group Age  ID
m      a     25   A01 
f      a     60   F05 
m      b     45   B03
f      b     35   A02
```

So I tried with aggraeate function but I don't know how to attach the ID to it

```
aggregate(Age~Gender+Group,data1,min)

Gender Group Age  
m      a     25    
f      a     60    
m      b     45  
f      b     35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data1)`). If it is to get the row corresponding to the `min` of 'Age', we use `which.min` to get the row index of the `min` 'Age' grouped by 'Gender', 'Group' and then use that to subset the rows (`.SD[which.min(Age)]`).

```
setDT(data1)[, .SD[which.min(Age)], by = .(Gender, Group)]
```

Or another option would be to `order` by 'Gender', 'Group', 'Age', and then get the first row using `unique`.

```
unique(setDT(data1)[order(Gender,Group,Age)], 
                         by = c('Gender', 'Group'))
```

---

Or using the same methodology with `dplyr`,  we use `slice` with `which.min` to get the corresponding 'Age' grouped by 'Gender', 'Group'.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
    group_by(Gender, Group) %>%
    slice(which.min(Age))
```

Or we can `arrange` by 'Gender', 'Group', 'Age' and then get the first row

```
data1 %>%
     arrange(Gender,Group, Age) %>%
     group_by(Gender,Group) %>%
     slice(1L)
```